# Determine whether a point is inside triangle in 3D space

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I have a 3D triangle that is represented by 3x 3D vertices.

I'm looking for an algorithm that must cover the following requirements:

1. a point lies on the same plane as defined by the triangle and
2. that the point resides within the boundaries of said triangle

for example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define basis vectors **b**=**AB**, **c**=**AC** and **n**= **b** x **c** (vector product), where A, B, C - triangle vertices's coordinates
Represent point P coordinate in this basis, solving [linear equation system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) (unknown t,u,v). [Gaussian elimination method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is suitable here.

```
t * b.X + u * c.X + v * n.X = P.X
t * b.Y + u * c.Y + v * n.Y = P.Y
t * b.Z + u * c.Z + v * n.Z = P.Z
```

Point is 'inside' according to your picture, if

```
0 <= t <= 1
0 <= u <= 1
and
t + u <= 1
```

Comment: could you give it more details how to find out (t, u, v) value?

Comment: @user3030712 Simply multiply P with the inverse of the matrix given by b, c, and n.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose **ABC** is your triangle, to know if a point is on the same plane as triangle ABC we can use [cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) product. If point **P** in on the same plane then,

```
(P-A).( (B-A)x(C-A) ) = 0 
here [.] is dot product and [x] is cross product.
A, B, C are co ordinates of vertex of the triangle
```

For (2), Simplest way is to use [Barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) to know if a point lies inside or on the boundary of a triangle. Any point P inside a triangle can be represented as

```
P = a*A + b*B + c*C where 0 <= a, b, c <= 1 and a+b+c = 1 
(on boundary if at least one of a,b,c is zero)
Now, we can write, a = 1 - b - c.
   P = (1-b-c)*A + b*B + c*C
=> P-A = b*(B-A) + c*(C-A)
```

Suppose, **X** = P-A, **Y** = B-A, **Z** = C-A. Then the equation becomes,

```
X = b*Y + c*Z
taking dot product with Y and Z, we get
X.Y = b*(Y.Y) + c*(Z.Y)
X.Z = b*(Y.Z) + c*(Z.Z)
define x1 = X.Y, y1 = Y.Y, z1 = Z.Y, 
       x2 = X.Z, y2 = Y.Z, z2 = Z.Z
```

Now we have to solve the following linear equation with two unknown.

```
x1 = b*y1 + c*z1
x2 = b*y2 + c*z2
```

solving these two equation we get,

```
b = (x1*z2 - x2*z1)/(y1*z2-y2*z1)
c = (-x1*y2 + x2*y1)/(y1*z2-y2*z1)
a = 1 - b - c

Then we can easily check if a,b,c satisfies the condition. 
(actually checking 0 <= b,c <= 1 and b+c <= 1 is enough)
```